# Retaincount abnormal behaviour while pushing a Viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, retaincount

```
 -(void)NewButton
    {
        ApplianceViewController *VC = [[ApplianceViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ApplianceViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] ;

        NSLog(@"Retain count before pushViewController:%d",VC.retainCount);//prints1 
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"Retain count after pushViewController:%d",VC.retainCount);//prints 7
        [VC release];
        NSLog(@"Retain count after Release:%d",VC.retainCount);// prints 6
    }
```

In my code retain count increases abnormally. I waisted lot of time. any help please.

Comment: Don't worry about it :) retainCount is just an implementation detail and don't sweat what it says. You really only need to focus on your reference count, which is when it is allocated, copied, or retained within your own code.

Comment: You shouldn't care about this for several reasons. 1) You should be using ARC by now. 2) Never look at the retain count for proper memory management. 3) You don't know `UINavigationController`'s internal implementation, so you also don't know if that `retainCount` is right or not.

Comment: right,  but in this scenario i'm taking care of retainCount because dealloc method for ApplianceViewController is not being called as retainCount is not dropped to zero, and i'm facing memory crash issues after some navigations.

Comment: Dealloc won't be called until the view controller is popped from the navigation stack anyway. If you do have memory management problems, they aren't in this code.

Comment: Currently i'm taking care of retainCount, because dealloc method of, ApplianceViewController, is not being called(when I pop it out back) as retainCount is not dropped to zero.

Answer (score 1):

## The absolute retainCount of an object is meaningless.

See:  http://www.whentouseretaincount.com for more details.

The retain counts you are seeing are internal implementation details of the frameworks.  They are, effectively, meaningless.  More likely than not, the retain count is as high as it is in that code because you are tangling the view controller into an animation, which requires multiple references and some complex behind the scenes issues.

The code you posted is not the problem.

Use the Allocations instrument with "track live references only" and "track reference counts" turned on.   Then reproduce your leak and click through to the inventory of retain/release events for the object in question.   That'll give you a list of exactly where the object is retained (and released) which will tell you exactly why it is still in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have one property

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutLet UITableView myTableView;

I was getting reference from nib file.  I've just replaced retain with assign.  And problem was solved.